# How does <img src="path"> works?

Tags: web, server, backend, web-deployment

How does an img tag works on browser?
If I have set src property to some image hosted online, and I use that in my app. Then from what I know is our app will download the image from that url and render it inside our application. But I'm confused about how will the load distribution be? What part of load will come on our server(say we are fetching that url from an API) and what will come on the url's server?

I'm actually using google's photo api(which returns url of the image hosted on their server) to render the images on my webpage.
So the download would be from their server but say if the image size is 4mb then will our network call also download 4mb since in the end the image is on our html

Comment: The HTML comes from your server or your app.  The image comes 100% from the other server.  Be careful, this can be considered "leeching" if that second server belongs to someone else, and they might have code running to break the download.   Also, since it is a "static" file the other server you could use cloud storage (Amazon AWS S3 storage, etc.) or from a content delivery network.

Comment: ``What I'm trying to do is make API calls to fetch image urls and then displaying those images using an img tag.``  -- an API call made from the local client?  Then your img tag should probably be `src=file://...` with a path to where you stored the image on the local device.

Comment: No @DaveS I'm actually using google's photo api to render the images on my webpage.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include more details: what is making the API call, where the file is copied to, what the src= link is pointing to.

Comment: @DaveS I've made the edits now

Comment: Thanks.  My first comment applies:  the HTML page  comes from your server, the image comes directly from Google's server to the client, not using your server at all.

Answer (score 0):

One of the big innovations of when the World Wide Web was first invented, was that it combined two concepts:

- The identity/name of a thing (like a document or image)
- The instructions on how to find it

And it packs those in a URL. So the great thing about browsers was that you no longer needed tell it what server to connect to find the thing you want. The browser just looks at a URL, and will connect to server with the name from the 'host' part of the URL, using the port in URL and protocol and retrieve the path.

So given:

```
<img src="http://example/image.jpg" />
```

The browser has everything it needs to find the image, and will do so without needing help from the server that rendered that image tag.